# How to get a specific number part from a string using regex

Tags: python, regex

```
result = ['\nR0        16082219            16.9(5r)                            ']
```

I need to put "16082219" into a variable. Kindly help me with regex in python. I tried many things, but did not work.

Comment: Have you tried regex101.com?

Comment: Also, please edit your answer to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely correct. What are you looking for? A sequence of 8 digits? Number between spaces? Second word? Second word from end of line? Look at a few answers for python3, they will all find the same thing using completely different regular expressions.

```
import re
result = ['\nR0 16082219 16.9(5r) ']
re_d8 = re.compile(r'(?P<d8>\d{8})')
m_d8 = re_d8.search(result[0])  # search for eight digits
if m_d8:
    print(f"d8={m_d8.group('d8')}")

re_2 = re.compile(r'[^ ]+ +(?P<digits>\d+) +')  # search for second word which contains only digits
m_2 = re_2.search(result[0])
if m_2:
    print(f"digits={m_2.group('digits')}")

re_3 = re.compile(r'(?P<d3>\d+) [^ ]+ $')  # search for the second word from the end
m_3 = re_3.search(result[0])
if m_3:
    print(f"d3={m_3.group('d3')}")

re_sDs = re.compile(r' (?P<sds>\d+) ')  # search for numbers between spaces
m_sds = re_sDs.search(result[0])
if m_sds:
    print(f"sds={m_sds.group('sds')}")
```